# SSIS: Is It possible to have modularity and avoid replication inside a single Data Flow?

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, bids, msbi

How I can do something like programming language functions/methods inside a Data Flow? I have data flows that have many steps sequence replication and I don't want that.

Using programming language as example, what I want:

```
task1;
task2;
insert();
....
task13;
task14;
insert();
....
task60;
task61;
insert();

//insert implementation
insert()
{
   logtask;
   insertInDatabaseAtask;
   insertInDatabaseBtask;
   audittask;
}
```

I know that break my package flow in more data flows is a possibility, but in certain cases, I prefer to do some modularity like methods/functions of programming language inside the same data flow.

Is it possible? How I can do that?

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: Can you help me understand your question? I don't understand how you'd like to be using methods/functions within a data flow. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Bilinkc, I have a great data flow that have some steps sequence that repeat some times, maybe 3/ 4 times, in differents locations inside the DataFlow....but this is a problem, because if something change in my businessrule, I would have to change the same step sequence and this is dangerous, because I may forget of some place. So I want something like a method/function of programming language, avoiding replication in my business rule. Example: 4 places have 'StepA, StepB,StepC', in the future stepB is removed from the business rule, so I would have to change the 4 places.

Comment: Practical example: One of my Data Flows have more than 10 error outputs in the flow. And is always the same...I register in file, I register in database, I change Audit table. And I am repeating this sequence 10 times in my data flow, 10 different files output files generated( because SSIS don't have concurrency control in files, and doesn't allow 2 tasks writing in the same file at same time ). This is one example practical, but I have others not related to error conditions

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of your great dataflow would help me understand what you're looking to simplify. Is part of the challenge that you'd like to collect all the error streams into a single output file?

Comment: SSIS already writes to an error log. I suggest you let it do that, then process the error log afterwards if you need more complicated reporting.

Comment: and of course the best way to implement repeated database functions is implement them in a stored proc and just call it

Comment: Nick, I am doing that, using stored procedure in repeated database functions, and this is  simplifying a lot my flows. About 'SSIS already writes to an error log'. This is new to me. I searched in the server for something like that and I not found nothing. Because that I begin to write my own logs. Neither the 'Progress Log' of Visual Studio I found in the server. I use the SQL Server Agent to run my packages in server